# WPF DataGrid inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I have a `StackPanel` with a header control and a `DataGrid` Inside a `Scrollviewer`; like so:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Canvas x:Name="header" 
                Height="300" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The scoll behavior should fulfill these requirements:

- Scrolling while MouseOver the `DataGrid` should scroll the outer `ScrollViewer`
- The header control (symbolized by `Canvas`) is scrolled by the `ScollViewer`.
- The horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the `DataGrid` should be preserved on screen at any time.
- The horizontal scrollbar should not scroll the header control, only the `DataGrid`.

I tried various settings for the `DataGrid.ScrollViewer` but none have the desired effect, nor does changing the `StackPanel` to a `WrapPanel` or even `Grid` help any.

Is this possible? Any help and resources to read are appreciated.

Comment: What's the parent element of the `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: @mm8 The parent element of `ScrollViewer` is a `UserControl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been struggling with your first problem for some time as well - having an inner ScrollViewer (or DataGrid in this case) scroll the outer ScrollViewer. But I think I have a pretty elegant solution. You have to add an event handler to the PreviewMouseWheel event of the DataGrid (and a name to the ScrollViewer):

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll_viewer">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Canvas x:Name="header" 
                Height="300" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" PreviewMouseWheel="mousewheel">
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then the event handling method:

```
private void mousewheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    //what we're doing here, is that we're invoking the "MouseWheel" event of the parent ScrollViewer.

    //first, we make the object with the event arguments (using the values from the current event)
    var args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);

    //then we need to set the event that we're invoking.
    //the ScrollViewer control internally does the scrolling on MouseWheelEvent, so that's what we're going to use:
    args.RoutedEvent = ScrollViewer.MouseWheelEvent;

    //and finally, we raise the event on the parent ScrollViewer.
    scroll_viewer.RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Took some tweaking, but got it to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's a very complicated question, it probably requires a man-week to complete! But here's a start which solves half of your problem:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Canvas x:Name="header" Height="300" />
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </DataGrid.Template>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you put the canvas inside the datagrid's template it will consider it as a part of the datagrid so canvas and datagrid will be scrolled as one.

Obviously, the datagrid template will be blank this way, showing no headers. Therefore you need to rewrite it from the scratch. You may use [the default source code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates) for this purpose.

To find the template just search for `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">`
in the given link.